# What are the practical use of weak semaphores?

Tags: semaphore

Weak semaphores are often defined as

> if a process (or thread), say p1, performs a V operation and some
>   other process is waiting on that semaphore, then the first process
>   (i.e. p1) is not allowed to immediately perform another P operation on
>   that semaphore. Instead, one of the waiting processes must be given
>   its turn.

Further, while a single weak-semaphore cannot guarantee starvation-freedom, using few of them can actually guarantee starvation-freedom.
Can anyone mention any practical use of such weak-semaphores!

^*The quoted section is from S. A. Friedberg and G. L. Peterson, "An Efficient Solution to the Mutual Exclusion Problem Using Weak Semaphores" with a bit embellishment*